# Openlayers Vector label density

Tags: openlayers, style, vector-tiles

I am rendering vector tiles and the roads are made up of many line segments. Each segment has a line layer and symbol layer in the vector tile.

I am getting repeated labels along main roads made up of many segments as shown below. Is there a way to space them out further?

I've tried using:-

```
padding: [100,100,100,100]
```

But this seems to have no effect. I'm using Openlayers 4 and have also tried in Openlayers 5 with same problem.

[image]

Style is essentially this:-

```
{padding: [100,100,100,100], text: "A19",  placement: "line", fill: ..., stroke: ..., font: ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It is not ideal but helps.

I created a global array

```
 window.labelcachearray = ['','','','','','','','','','',''];
```

In my style I then push label names to this array and return undefined if the name exists. I make sure the array shifts and this works well enough with repeated road names.

```
//prevent label repetition over last ten labels horrible hack 
positioning issue with road labels
        if(window.labelcachearray.includes(properties.name)){
           return undefined;
       }

        window.labelcachearray.unshift(properties.name);
        window.labelcachearray.pop();
```

I know! I know! I KNOW!!!! There are all sorts of issues but for UK road names it works and I cannot think of a better solution outside of hacking Openlayers